# ¿"Echar una siesta" o "hacer una siesta"?

Tags: diferencias-regionales

Me pregunto si se puede decir `"hacer una siesta"` en lugar de `"echar una siesta"`.

En general, en el castellano de España, asumo que "echar una siesta" es lo correcto por algo tan poco científico como que es lo que suena bien y el resto no tanto. Incluso el verbo lo indica en una de sus acepciones:

> **[echar](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=NC56LCsY9DXX23RefXXq)**
>
> 25. tr. Junto con algunos nombres, tiene la significación de los verbos que se forman de ellos o la de otros equivalentes. Echar
>       maldiciones, maldecir; echar suertes, sortear; echar un cigarro,
>       fumarlo; echar un sueño, dormir; echar la siesta, sestear.

Sin embargo, leyendo el debate en Wordreference: [hacer / tomar / dormir / echar(se) la siesta](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/hacer-tomar-dormir-echar-se-la-siesta.1194862/) veo que alguien menciona:

> En Argentina, más que nada en el campo, algunas personas dicen:
>   "Fulano se hizo una siesta de dos horas"...

Por lo que me surge la duda: ¿en qué lugares se usa "echar" y en cuáles "hacer"? ¿Es una expresión "idiomática" u obedece a alguna otra razón?

Comment: You can use any of them, they all are valids and everyone is going understand you even if they are not used to one of them. In this case is the same as pronunciation of the english language in different countries. Imagine one having to memorize and use the correct pronunciation of english words while being on England or USA. Now, for me, _dormir la siesta_ is redundant.

Comment: Para mi ambas son igualmente válidas. En Colombia usamos las dos 50/50. Curioso que la respuesta que aceptaste niega rotundamente una de ellas mientras que la más votada la contradice.

Comment: @DGaleano tienes razón, no me había dado cuenta de la tendencia. A ver si alguien más comenta, pues por lo que parece no hay ni mucho menos unanimidad al respecto.

Comment: Pues yo he oído decir _hacer siesta_ a gente de Barcelona, en otros sitios siempre he oído _echar una/la siesta_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay una pregunta anterior que es similar a esta por el uso del verbo `hacer` para una acción determinada: [Hacer sentido V. Tener sentido](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/15289/5481)

Para esta pregunta encontramos que "tener sentido" es la forma correcta y "hacer sentido" es una traducción literal de las forma del inglés "to make sense" (según la Academia de la Lengua Mexicana).

Viendo las respuestas ya aportadas parece ser que se usa "hacer" para la siesta en Cataluña y Valencia debido  `a un vínculo idiomático fuerte, ya que en catalán muchas de las expresiones que tenemos en castellano las construyen con el verbo "hacer"`. El valenciano es muy similar al catalán (aunque alguno querrá tirarme piedras por decir esto...) Así que de nuevo vemos `hacer` usado debido a una influencia lingüística de otro idioma. Alguien aporta que para aquellos influenciados por el gallego, esto no ocurre.

La respuesta de Elisa valida que no en toda Argentina se usa "hacer la siesta", por lo que creo que la referencia que citas en la preguna es un caso particular, y también afectado por la influencia de otro idioma.

Así que yo concluiría que en castellano no se dice "hacer la siesta" (sino dormir o echarse la siesta) y cuando oímos a alguien decir "hacer la siesta" es por influencia de otro idioma.

Por cierto, también poodemos decir `echarse un cigarro` (por fumárselo), pero `hacerse un cigarro` ya es algo completamente distinto (envolverlo con tabaco de liar; fabricarlo).

Comment: Tiene sentido :-)

Comment: La alternativa argentina "hacer la siesta" possiblemente venga del portugués, en el que se dice "fazer a sesta".

Answer (score 6):

En mi experiencia, "hacer una siesta" es la expresión mas común que existe en Cataluña para referirse a "echar la siesta".

Si no me equivoco, corresponde a un vínculo idiomático fuerte, ya que en catalán muchas de las expresiones que tenemos en castellano las construyen con el verbo "hacer". Por ello, castellanizan la construcción catalana, habiéndose convertido en expresiones de uso común en el castellano de Cataluña. Por ejemplo, en vez de decir "dar un beso" dicen "hacer besos".

Por lo que sé, Cataluña es de los sitios de la península ibérica que más utilizan "hacer" en vez de "echar", cosa que en el resto de la península no ocurre.

En cuanto a las variaciones en Hispanoamérica, si no me equivoco, Argentina y sus países vecinos lo construyen de la misma manera.

Comment: ¡Gracias por la respuesta! Siendo catalanoparlante, nunca he oído "hacer un beso".

Comment: Son catalanadas que de vez en cuanto he tenido el placer de oír.

Answer (score 2):

Probablemente haya variaciones importantes incluso dentro de cada país, así que no puedo hablar por toda Argentina. En Buenos Aires uno diría "dormir la siesta". 
"Echarse una siesta" también es posible, pero suena muy informal.
"Hacer una siesta" no lo escuché nunca.

Answer (score 2):

Por mi parte, suelo usar "tomar la siesta", eso proviene de mi padre, que es gallego. No recuerdo haberlo oido yo mismo en Galicia u otra parte de España, pero quizás sí.

Answer (score 1):

Sin duda alguna, a excepción al parecer de casos como el que comenta fedorqui de Cataluña (curioso, no se lo he escuchado nunca a ningún amigo ni familiar catalán, aunque supongo que si lo dices será porque lógicamente lo has escuchado), en el resto de España se usa la fórmula **"Echar una siesta"** o **"echarse la siesta"** mientras que "hacer una siesta" no lo he escuchado jamás en mi vida, a nadie, en ningún contexto.

Answer (score 1):

En España se dice "echarse la siesta". Se utiliza el verbo "echar" con significado de tumbar o reposar porque te echas en el sofá o la cama.

El verbo "Tomar" se utiliza para comer por lo que no *"tomamos la siesta"*.

El verbo "hacer" se utiliza como acción pero no decimos *"hacer la siesta"*.

Answer (score 1):

En España se dice de las dos formas, depende mucho de la región o ciudad. Por ejemplo, en Albacete se utiliza "echar" y en Valencia se utiliza habitualmente "hacer" para referirnos a la siesta. Entre Valencia y Albacete hay unos 185 kilómetros de separación (muy poco).

Ejemplo en Valencia:

> ¿vas a hacer siesta?

Ejemplo en Albacete:

> ¿te vas a echar la siesta?

Observad que en Valencia es también común omitir el artículo entre el verbo y la palabra siesta.

Seguro que hay gente en Valencia que dice "echar la siesta", y tal vez alguien dice "hacer siesta" en Albacete, siempre hay excepciones.

He vivido muchos años en ambos sitios.

Answer (score 1):

Yo creo que hacer una siesta también es correcto.
 Si consideramos la siesta como una acción que puede realizarse.
Igual que es correcto :
   -"Voy a hacer un viaje por toda Europa".
   -"Este domingo, voy a hacer una carrera de 10 
       Km".
   -"Después del COU hice la carrera de medicina".
 También es correcto;
   -"Esta tarde voy a hacer una siesta de dos horas".
   -"Después del spinning hice una siesta de media 
     hora"

Comment: Me gusta tu logica.  Otro ejemplo: Escribo un post, hago un post.

Answer (score 1):

Es curioso la de cosas que se pueden hacer con la siesta :))) , desde luego que donde se supone que se habla el castellano más puro, vamos a dejarlo en Castilla - León sin más precisión, se dice echar la siesta